# Hammer.js pinchin/pinchout events not firing (How to debug android)

Tags: javascript, android, pinchzoom, hammer.js

I'm using hammer.js to capture pinch events in order to simulate zooming in and out, however none of the events are firing when I test it with my Galaxy Tab 2 (android 4.1)

html:

```
<img class='image' src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-1073-779-9.jpg"></img>
```

script:

```
$(function(){
var imageElems = $('.image');
alert('count: '+imageElems.length); //returns 'count: 1'

imageElems.hammer({prevent_default:true})
    .on("pinchin", function (evt)
    {
        alert('zoom out');
        //more stuff
    }).on("pinchout", function (evt)
    {
        alert('zoom in');
        //more stuff
    }); 


//this alert doesn't fire on android device (not tested on any other)
alert('done');
});
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7EV56/6/

The second alert never fires on android. I'm assuming it's because there is an error, but it doesn't happen in the browser on my PC (but then I can't test pinch-ing). How do I find out what error occured in android chrome.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Got it. I was serving the hammer.js library directly from GitHub, but they purposefully serve it with a MIME type of text/plain wich is not executable in chrome.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=180007

The main issue however was not being able to debug it on my tablet, but now I have installed the chrome [ADB plugin](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) which helped a lot. Once I spotted the actual error it was easy.